# How to select a default country with ngx-intl-tel-input

Tags: angular, npm

I am using [ngx-intl-tel-input](https://github.com/webcat12345/ngx-intl-tel-input) in order to have an international phone number field in my `Angular 7` project.

I would like to be able to set the default country of the dropdown (and therefore the accompanying placeholder) by either:

- using the country code that the user has provided in another area of
  the form or,
- if the above is not provided, using the country code of the users' IP
  address

Based on the documentation for this package, I don't see a way to set a default country, only a way to set preferred countries for the dropdown and having the first country in that array auto-selected

Any thoughts on how to achieve this, other than the obvious workaround of dynamically injecting desired value for default country into the first index of the `preferredCountries` array?

** Update **
The reason why I did not want to use the `preferredCountries` array for this because then I would need it to change dynamically. I have not been able to find a way to change the dropdown countries live this since the ngx-intl-tel-input component sets the countries listed in `preferredCountries` by implementing `OnInit`

```
    ngOnInit() {

    this.fetchCountryData();

    if (this.preferredCountries.length) {
        this.preferredCountries.forEach(iso2 => {
            const preferredCountry = this.allCountries.filter((c) => {
                return c.iso2 === iso2;
            });

            this.preferredCountriesInDropDown.push(preferredCountry[0]);
        });
    }
    if (this.onlyCountries.length) {
        this.allCountries = this.allCountries.filter(c => this.onlyCountries.includes(c.iso2));
    }
    if (this.preferredCountriesInDropDown.length) {
        this.selectedCountry = this.preferredCountriesInDropDown[0];
    } else {
        this.selectedCountry = this.allCountries[0];
    }
```

If you know of a way to work around this issue, I'd be happy to use the `preferredCountries` array to achieve my  desired behavior, however the above is what is blocking me from doing so at the moment.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 5):

As shown on github, you can set the `[preferredCountries]="[yourDefaultCountryCode]"`, for example this will show Great Britain:

```
<ngx-intl-tel-input 
    [cssClass]="'custom'" 
    [preferredCountries]="['gb']" <!-- THIS ONE -->
    [enablePlaceholder]="true"
    [enableAutoCountrySelect]="true"
    name="phone" 
    formControlName="phone"></ngx-intl-tel-input>
```

Comment: thanks for your prompt feedback, however this is exactly the workaround that I am trying to avoid. Instead I was asking if there were any alternative solutions, one that did not include tampering with the preferred countries array.

Comment: I see it as the proper way of doing it, why not?

Answer (score 0):

you can use **ng2-tel-input** it works for angular 2+ [enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-tel-input)

and use this for Ex to set Egypt as default country
[ng2TelInputOptions]="{initialCountry: 'eg'}", "eg" -> "Egypt".

```
<input [(ngModel)]="Phone_Number" required type="tel" ng2TelInput (hasError)="hasError($event)" (ng2Tel[][1]Output)="getNumber($event)" (intlTelInputObject)="telInputObject($event)" (countryChange)="onCountryChange($event)" [ng2TelInputOptions]="{initialCountry: 'eg'}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

in TS :

```
import { CountryISO, SearchCountryField } from 'ngx-intl-tel-input';
CountryISO = CountryISO;
```

in HTML :

```
<ngx-intl-tel-input [selectedCountryISO]="CountryISO.India" ...> </ngx-intl-tel-input>
```